# Firebird 4 Get "Incompatible data type" error when using gsec or isql

Tags: firebird, firebird-4.0

I'm facing an issue when I try to use gsec or isql on v4.0.1:

```
# "${PREFIX}"/bin/gsec -database "security.db" -display MYUSER
Incompatible data type
```

Or via isql:

```
# "${PREFIX}"/bin/isql -user sysdba security.db
Database: security.db, User: SYSDBA
SQL> create or alter user SYSDBA password '${ISC_PASSWORD}' using plugin Srp;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000
no operation specified
-Incompatible data type
```

I've deleted then recreated security4.fdb and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Do you have `DataTypeCompatibility` configured in `firebird.conf`, and if so what is its value?

Comment: DataTypeCompatibility = 2.5. So if I remove this, setting, I'll have to check all the applications libraries to see if still working right?

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this error on Firebird 4.0.1 (on Windows), and it doesn't occur, where it does occur with Firebird 4.0.0. This suggests that you're still using Firebird 4.0.0 (or you have a mix of components from different versions).

Comment: ho my bad, I confirm I'm in 4.0.0 :/

Comment: I've upgraded to 4.0.1 and I confirm that the error doesn't occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/6860 and it is supposed be fixed in version 4.0.1. Check server version twice or just remove DataTypeCompatibility setting from firebird.conf.

Comment: A potential workaround would be to remove the `DataTypeCompatibility` setting from `firebird.conf`, and only configure it on the databases that need it.

Comment: I removed DataTypeCompatibility that was previously setted on 2.5. I have to check if I could get new issues with our legacy applications.

Comment: @ebelair You should be able to set it per-database using `databases.conf`.

Comment: All of our databases are migrated from 2.5 :D

Comment: Alternative workaround, add `DataTypeCompatibility =` (that is, with an empty value) to the `security.db` entry in `databases.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for the tricks, I didn't know for the empty value. I did the inverse, adding the setting in each database